# unable to create new users with firebase. I keep getting error message "updateChildValues: at / failed: permission_denied"

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I taught myself how to code online a little over a year ago. Im making very little progress with my own app. When trying to create a new user, I keep getting the same error code. "updateChildValues: at / failed: permission_denied" Below I will post a copy of my code, please help me it.

```
@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
@IBAction func Signup(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

if txtUserName.text != "" && txtPassword.text != ""
    {

    }
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: txtUserName.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
        if user != nil
        {
            //Sign in successful
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }
        else
        {

        }

       if let myError = error?.localizedDescription
       {
        print(myError)
        }
       else{
        print("Error")
        }
    }

    let ref =  Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://odd-jobs-llc.firebaseio.com/")
    observeKeyboardNotifications()

    ref.updateChildValues(["Customers": 123123])
}
```

Please help me get over this brick wall. I would really appreciate it. Thank you have a great night
 Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!



// Assuming this is the button you want to tap to signup the user
@IBAction func Signup(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if txtUserName.text != "" && txtPassword.text != "" {
      Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: txtUserName.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
          if user != nil {
              print("Registration success! Now I can do whatever I want in this block")
          } else {
             // telling you what went wrong
             print(error?.localizedDescription)
          }
      }
    } else {
      print("One of your field is empty")
    }

@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {

    if txtUserName.text != "" && txtPassword.text != "" {
       Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: txtUserName.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) { (user, error) in

        if user != nil {
            //Sign in successful
            let ref =  Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://odd-jobs-llc.firebaseio.com/")
            observeKeyboardNotifications()
            ref.updateChildValues(["Customers": 123123])
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

        } else {

           if let myError = error?.localizedDescription {
               print(myError)
           } else{
               print("Error")
           }
        }


    }

   }
}
```

Comment: I have email authenticated, the rules are the exact same. Is there anything else I’m missing? I have two separate view controllers for my sign up and login should I post the code for the other one?  However they are almost identical

Comment: @ZachWilcox i think ive found your problem.

Comment: hello John Doe! I have the Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: txtUserName.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) set up on my register view controller. which I thought would allow me to register new users. However, I keep getting that error code and no data is saved in my firebase authentication. Is there something off with my code?  I have all of my outlets set up I'm just not sure what else there is to do.

Comment: Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.Email.text!, password: self.Password.text!) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil
            {
       this is what my register view controller lines look like

Comment: the code you've putted about has the signIn method instead of the createUser method so I thought maybe you had a typo that's causing the problem. In your Appdelegate.swift did you add the FirebaseApp.configure() in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method? Also, check to see if you have the GoogleService-Info.plist in your xcode project

Comment: @ZachWilcox also in your if statement there's nothing in that block. I assume you want to have the Auth.auth() method in there.

Comment: Yea I hve the plist and the configure. Which if statement are you talking about? Could you show me??

Comment: I get this response in my error box updateChildValues: at / failed: permission_denied
When i go to log in. However when I do click sign up, and I do register a user, it says log in successful which I made it print. Even though it did not save the email and password to the data base, it did save this in my tree log on firebase "customers: 123123
                         newuserdata: 1" I feel like im getting so close however im still so far!

Comment: also, When I click the signup button, It doesnt sign the user up. it redirects to a sign up view controller. which in turn has more code on it. I know I am being rather confusing I feel like it would be so much easier if you could just see my project

Comment: @ZachWilcox if i recall correctly firebase won't show you the password the user registered with his/her email (but the email should be visible to you in Authentication in your console under USERS identifiers) also you are sure that in your Realtime Database the rules is the same as the default?

Comment: @ZachWilcox post a few screen shots of your project. It'll help us

Comment: /Users/zachwilcox/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-02-08 at 10.31.10 PM.png/Users/zachwilcox/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-02-08 at 10.31.31 PM.png/Users/zachwilcox/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-02-08 at 10.33.05 PM.png/Users/zachwilcox/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-02-08 at 10.34.17 PM.png

Comment: I thought that would add a screenshot I apologize

Comment: @ZachWilcox or upload it to imgur and give us the link (or better yet upload your project to github)

Comment: what is your username for github? Im uploading my project now

Comment: all of my files are uploaded to github

Comment: @ZachWilcox can you give us the link ?

Comment: https://github.com/patskid315/odd- here is the link! it is register view controller, view controler, and vc2. I tried to upload the story board as well but it came out janky

Comment: @ZachWilcox why is your sign-in method inside viewdidload?

Comment: @ZachWilcox viewdidload is immediately called when the view loads and only once. Therefore, even if you type anything into your textfields nothing will happen. Have you tried the code I've provided above? So your signin method isn't in viewdidload but rather in a IBAction button

Comment: Im sorry I read the comment wrong, I previously thought that is where it was supposed to be..

Comment: so for the register vc and the vc 1, the sign in and sign up methods have to be called before the view did load? @johndoe

Comment: @ZachWilcox no the sign-in and createUser methods should be called in whichever buttons you want them to be called (i.e. signInButton contains the sign-in method and signUpButton contains the createUser method)

Comment: thank you @johndoe! I changed it to match what you gave me and I keep getting the error expected declaration

Comment: @ZachWilcox at where and what did xcode say? update it to your github as well

Comment: ! thank you so much!! I just deleted all of my code and copy and pasted yours into where mine should've been! it allows me to save the data to my firebase console however it doesn't redirect me. That is minor compared to what you have done for me so far! if there is anyway I can pay you to feel free to reach out. I have a great idea for an app, I'm just an intermediate coder who is trying to teach myself! you my friend, are a wizard

Comment: I have been stuck on this roadblock for three days now, and out of nowhere, you save the day. much appreciation @johndoe

Comment: @ZachWilcox lol that's great then buddy. Keep up the good work and help others as much as you can too !

Comment: thank you very much! ill definitely  I just have two final questions! I had a facebook SDK implemented in my view and it disappeared. Also, I had a border colors set for my text fields and they disappeared as well! do you know what I did to have them disappear? they were once highlighted in their respective colors, no they're all white. Even if not, I still really appreciate what you've has done.

Comment: @ZachWilcox I am probably not suitable to answer the Facebook SDK problem since I haven't had the time to experiment with it yet. For the textfield part do mytextfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor (this sets the color of your border to black).  mytextfield.layer.borderWidth = 1 (sets your borderwidth) but iirc there are better ways to do this since it's graphic intensive? (need someone to check this for me)

Comment: does this have to be before view did load as well? @johndoe

Comment: @ZachWilcox do this inside override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      mytextfield1.layer.borderwidth = 1
      mytextfield1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
       
}

Answer (score 0):

See the [Firebase quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

By default the database is only readable/writeable by authenticated users. You must allow unauthenticated access to your database.

Comment: do you know how I would do so?